# Reentrancy Attack -How to do it on this sell function?

Tags: reentrant-attacks

Hey there guys how are u , can someone help me on this ? 
I want to do a **REENTRANCY** on this Dex , ***how can i change the code on sell function to stell ETH*** ,when somebody wanna sell theyr token throught sell function ?
https://ethereum.org/en/developers/tutorials/transfers-and-approval-of-erc-20-tokens-from-a-solidity-smart-contract/

The function is this :

```
function sell(uint256 amount) public {
    
  require(amount > 0, "You need to sell at least some tokens");
   
  uint256 allowance = token.allowance(msg.sender, address(this));
    
  require(allowance >= amount, "Check the token allowance");
    
  token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount);
    
  msg.sender.transfer(amount);
 
  emit Sold(amount);

}
```

**How To Modify this function to make it vulnerable to reentrancy ?**
#PLEASEHELP

Answer (score 1):

The function you mentioned doesn't use any contract state, so it has a good resistance to reentrancy attacks. In general, to enable a function to be abused with a reentrancy attack, you will need to make it change the local state of the contract after an external call. your function might be changed to something like this :

```
mapping(address => uint256) allowances;

function sell(uint256 amount) public {
    
  require(amount > 0, "You need to sell at least some tokens");
       
  require(allowances[msg.sender] >= amount, "Check the token allowance");

  msg.sender.transfer(amount);  

  token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount);
 
  allowances[msg.sender].sub(amount)
  
  emit Sold(amount);

}
```

as you can see, here we can recall the same `sell` function before the first have subtracted the amount from the allowances and thus being able to sell again even if the sender doesn't have a sufficient allowance.

Note: The original function might be exploitable via a cross contract reentrancy attack since it doesn't check if the `token.transferFrom` has succeeded or not although that seems to be a standard error.